# Возведение числа в степень и получение младшего разряда

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Функция возвращает последнюю цифру числа, но если число слишком большое то infinity, как обработать число чтобы не возвращалось infinity?

```
var lastDigit = function(str1, str2){
    var result =  Math.pow(+str1,+str2).toString().split('');
    var elem = +result[result.length - 1];
    console.log(elem);
};
```

```
lastDigit("4", "1");           //       4 => 4
lastDigit("4", "2");           //      16 => 6
lastDigit("9", "7");           // 4782969 => 9
lastDigit("10","10000000000"); //=> 0
```

Comment: А что тогда должно возвращать? Используйте длинную арифметику, чтобы найти очень большие числа.

Comment: все равно нужно обработать число и получить последнюю цифру, но я ее не могу получить так как   result = infinity/

Comment: в смысле длинную арифметику?

Comment: Это же просто остаток от деления на 10 квадрата последней цифры `str1` (наверное давно в столбик не умножали?)

Comment: @avp, это для какого случая? например для 2 в степени 7 последняя цифра будет 8 (128). По твоему алгоритму: 2*2 %10 = 4. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: @Grundy, в самом деле. Это работает для однократного умножения. Тогда надо считать в цикле с количеством повторов равным показателю степени.  Что-то вроде int d1 = nstr1 % 10, d2 = d1; for (int i = 0; i < nstr2; i++) d1 = (d1 * d2) % 10; return d1;`

Comment: @avp, можно еще эмпирических правил добавить, например, если последняя цифра 5 или 6 - то нет смысла умножать в цикле - последняя цифра результата все равно будет той же самой

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы возводите первый аргумент в степень, выраженную вторым аргументом, и находите младший десятичный разряд результата. Выражаясь математически:     *x<sup>y</sup> (mod 10)*

Это классическая задача теории чисел, имеющая широкое применение и готовые решения, не требующие вычислять отдельно x^y.

Простейший алгоритм основан на том факте, что *(a * b) (mod m) == (a * (b (mod m))) (mod m)*

```
function lastDigit(base, exponent) { 
    var c = 1; 
    for (i = 1; i <= exponent; i++) c = (c * base) % 10; 
    return c; 
}
```

Существуют и другие более эффективные алгоритмы: [Алгоритмы быстрого возведения в степень по модулю](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E)